# Bound for generalised Matrix $(p, k)$-norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-norms, matrix-analysis

Generalised Matrix $(p, k)$-norm[1] generalizes Schatten and Ky-Fan norms as it is defined as follows:
$$
N_{p, k}(A) = (\sum_{i=1}^{k}\sigma_i^{p}(A))^{\frac{1}{p}}
$$
where $\sigma_i$ is i-th largest singular value of matrix $A$.

Let $A$, $B$ be $4\times 4$ complex matrices, such that:
$$
\text{tr}(A^\dagger A) + \text{tr}(B^\dagger B) = \frac{1}{4}
$$
where $A^{\dagger}$ is complex conjugate of $A$.

**I want to show that $[N_{2,2}(A+B)]^2 = [\sigma_1(A+B)]^2 + [\sigma_2(A+B)]^2  \leq \frac{1}{2}$.**

For any complex, $4 \times 4$ complex matrix $X$
$$
tr(X^{\dagger}X) = \sum_{i=1}^4(\sigma_i(X))^2 = [N_{2,4}(X)]^2 \\
N_{2,4}(X) \geq N_{2,2}(X) \\
[N_{2,4}(X)]^2 \geq [N_{2,2}(X)]^2 \\
$$

Because $N_{p,k}(A)$ is a norm, we have:
$$
N_{2,2}(A+B) \leq N_{2,2}(A) + N_{2,2}(B) \text{ (from triangle inequality)} \\ 
[N_{2,2}(A+B)]^2 \leq [N_{2,2}(A) + N_{2,2}(B)]^2 \\
[N_{2,2}(A+B)]^2 \leq [N_{2,2}(A)]^2  + [N_{2,2}(B)]^2 + 2 N_{2,2}(A)N_{2,2}(B) \\
[\sigma_1(A+B)]^2 + [\sigma_2(A+B)]^2  \leq [N_{2,2}(A)]^2  + [N_{2,2}(B)]^2 + 2 N_{2,2}(A)N_{2,2}(B)
$$

Now, we know that $[N_{2,4}(A)]^2 + [N_{2,4}(B)]^2 = \frac{1}{4}$, from that we have $[N_{2,2}(A)]^2 + [N_{2,2}(B)]^2 \leq \frac{1}{4}$. We can plug it above to obtain

$$
[\sigma_1(A+B)]^2 + [\sigma_2(A+B)]^2  \leq \frac{1}{4} + 2 N_{2,2}(A)N_{2,2}(B)
$$

Now, if we assign $a = N_{2,2}(A), b = N_{2,2}(B)$, then we want to find maximum value of $2ab$, given that $a^2+b^2 \leq \frac{1}{4}$ and $a, b \geq 0$. I double checked my calculations using wolframalpha ([source](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=FindMaximum%5B%7B2*a*b%2C+a%5E2%2Bb%5E2+%3C%3D+1%2F4%2C+a+%3E%3D0%2C+b+%3E%3D+0%7D%2C+%7Ba%2C+b%7D%5D)) and found out that maximum value of $2ab$ under above conditions is $\frac{1}{4}$. From that we have
$$
[\sigma_1(A+B)]^2 + [\sigma_2(A+B)]^2  \leq \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{2}
$$

*I am sure that there is an error somewhere along the lines, but I cannot find it* Otherwise it would be a trivial solution to a problem described [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.2613).

[1] List of papers that shows that $N_{p,k}$ is a norm - [link](http://www.njohnston.ca/2009/08/ky-fan-norms-schatten-norms-and-everything-in-between/#comment-117)

Comment: I can´t find a mistake along the lines either but looking in the paper I read $X=A\otimes I+I\otimes B$ (constraint (50)) and I guess that is not the same as $A+B$.

Comment: The [Kronecker sum](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckerSum.html)seems to be related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This boils down to computing two different squared Frobenius norms to bound your truncated squared Schatten 2 (Frobenius) norm.

$0\leq \big\Vert A-B\big\Vert_F^2$
$\implies \text{trace}\big(A^*B\big)+\text{trace}\big(B^*A\big)\leq \text{trace}\big(A^*A\big)+\text{trace}\big(B^*B\big)= \frac{1}{4}$

and
$[N_{2,2}(A+B)]^2$
$\leq [N_{2,4}(A+B)]^2$
$=  \big\Vert A+B\big\Vert_F^2$
$ = \text{trace}\big(A^*A\big)+\text{trace}\big(B^*B\big) + \Big(\text{trace}\big(A^*B\big)+\text{trace}\big(B^*A\big)\Big) $
$\leq \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}$
$=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: This looks like another proof of what the OP proved about the norm of $A+B$, the paper which the OP quoted presents a proof about the norm of $A\otimes I+I\otimes B$, which is the Kronecker sum of $A$ and $B$ if I got it right

Comment: @PeterMelech I'm not sure why you keep commenting about Kronecker sums.  Re-read the original post-- in particular the line that says "I want to show that...".  (and the ending where OP indicates a mistake must have been made).  I glanced at the paper but I addressed what OP asked.

Comment: Your answer is fine and the OP´s proof too, Theorem 1 in the paper is about the Kronecker sum of the involved matrices though, anyway +1